Trouble converting curl command to VB.NET
I'm trying to interact with an API that works on a token but getting stuck on just getting the token. I have a CURL command line which works fine and returns a token but I am clearly missing something when converting it to VB.
The curl command works fine:
curl --location "<URL>cas/v1/tickets" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Cookie: org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.LOCALE=en" --data-urlencode "username=<username>" --data-urlencode "<password>" --data-urlencode "service=<url>" --data-urlencode "token=true"

It even works in a much simpler form:
curl -d "username=<username>" -d "password=<username>" -d "token=true" "<url>/cas/v1/tickets"

Here's my code to try and achieve the same via VB.NET but I get a Bad Request error:
Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("<URL>/cas/v1/tickets"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.LOCALE=en")
request.Headers.Add("username", "<username>")
request.Headers.Add("password", "<password>")
request.Headers.Add("service", "<URL>")
request.Headers.Add("token", "true")

Dim responseContent As String = ""
Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)

End Using

I've also tried the simpler form with just username, password and token in the header but same result. Fairly sure it's something basic that I'm missing but going round in circles now.

Move to HttpClient, so you can POST the content body using the dedicated FormUrlEncodedContent class (accepts a collection of key/value pairs). It simplifies the process of URL-encoding the content
